# Property resets when changing Usercontrols DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I've constructed a "Manager" of "Widgets" where i have a ListView/GridView with widgets.

The ListView binds the SelectedItem to a SelectedWidget property on the (Manager) ViewModel.

The SelectedWidget binds to a Usercontrol called WidgetConfig via a DependencyProperty called "Widget" where you can modify the properties of the selected Widget.

In the WidgetConfig , there are 2 RadioButtons:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Lead" IsChecked="{Binding Widget.prop1, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=root}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Lead" IsChecked="{Binding Widget.prop2, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=root}" />
```

When i select the 'prop2', the INPC signal is correctly sent and the model is updated accordingly. If then i click on the 'prop1', the INPC signal is sent + i get an additional signal from the prop2 radiobutton.

Here's the problem:
if **i select prop2** and then select another Widget in the ListView. I get a INPC signal and prop2 has changed back to **false**!

what's going on ?

Some info:

- The WidgetConfiguration is implemented using PostSharp NotifyPropertyChanged aspect.
- The WidgetConfig UserControl is implemented by hand with DependencyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged interface

EDIT:

I've created a reproducible example here : https://github.com/Montago/INCP-DP-BindingExample

Comment: So where in your code do you set `prop2` back to `false`? Put a breakpoint in the setter of the property to find out. Or post some minimal code where your issue can be reproduced if you want anyone to be able to point out where your issue is.

Comment: It's being set by intercepted code: [Intercepted] Client.exe!.....SelectedWidget.set(...WidgetConfiguration value)

I'll see if i can excerpt a reproducible piece of code.

Comment: I've created Git Repo with an example

Comment: "Requires PostSharp"!? Did you try to remove `GroupName="Lead"`?

Comment: PostSharp is an AOP framework that makes it easy to make INPC objects...

Comment: GroupName is what makes RadioButtons function like RadioButtons. 
But i could of cause implement the whole XOR logic by hand (which i ended up doing using CheckBoxes instead)

Comment: ...and requires a license!? Are you really expecting anyone to buy one to be able to reproduce your issue? Good luck then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a chain of two-way bindings, which are changing values on your Model:

Two-way binding between ListControl.SelectedItem(DP) and the ViewModel.SelectedModel(INPC).

Two-way binding between ViewModel.SelectedModel(INPC) and ModelControl.ActiveModel(DP).

Two-way binding between ModelControl.ActiveModel(DP) and Model.Prop1/Model.Prop2/Model.Name(INPC).

When you select First, Second and then again First, Second's prop2 is overwritten to false by WPF data binding.

A way to fix this is to remove the two-way binding that makes the overwrite of prop2, i.e. specify Mode=OneWay on RadioButton bindings.

My guess of what is happening: RadioButton's logic and two-way binding. When Second is selected in the list box and you change the selection to First, WPF's data binding sets Prop1 radio button as selected (because First.prop1 == true). At that point, the second radio button is still selected, so to respect the group principle, it needs to get unselected. However, there is still the two-way binding active on the Prop2 radio and thus Second.prop2 gets set to false.